# In my VS2010 i am missing a reference

Tags: visual-studio, reference, add-in

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.ui.vsintegration.objectexplorer.aspx

this is missing i try to add but not able to find it in my .net references here is a screenshot
[image]

anyidea how to get this reference?

Comment: A quick google suggests it's in SqlWorkBench.Interfaces.dll. Remember namespace !=  assembly, that's simply a convention for us types in the real world

Comment: Thanks for the revelation, but how do i got about adding it? not sure how to do that

Comment: Ok figured and found where it was it is located here for the latest version of the SQL server (SQL 2012) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio

Comment: i got another reference using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer; not able to find what dll is this pls assist tks